# Replace multiple column values with values from other columns if pattern matches (row-wise) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

**Hello, folks!**

I have tried to find a solution to this following problem that I think it would be pretty simple. Perhaps it is (for some of you), but I couldn’t solve the problem yet. What do I want is to modify all zeros and ones from columns 6 to 10, replacing the 0 for the third column values, and 1 for the fourth values in a row-wise manner.

That’s a reproducible example:

```
# Creating dataframe vectors
chr= rep(10,10)
id= paste0("name", 1:10)
pos= seq(1,1000, length.out = 10)
allele1= c("T","T","G","G","C","T","C","C","G","C")
allele2= c("A","A","T","T","C","T","C","C","T","T")
col6= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col7= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col8= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col9= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col10= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)

df= data.frame(chr,id, pos, allele1, allele2, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10)
df

   chr     id  pos allele1 allele2 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
1   10  name1    1       T       A    1    1    1    1     1
2   10  name2  112       T       A    0    0    0    1     1
3   10  name3  223       G       T    1    0    1    1     0
4   10  name4  334       G       T    1    1    0    1     1
5   10  name5  445       C       C    0    0    1    0     1
6   10  name6  556       T       T    0    1    0    1     1
7   10  name7  667       C       C    0    1    0    0     1
8   10  name8  778       C       C    0    0    1    1     1
9   10  name9  889       G       T    1    1    1    1     0
10  10 name10 1000       C       T    0    1    1    0     1
```

Accordingly to this output, I would expect:

```
df
   chr     id  pos allele1 allele2 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
1   10  name1    1       T       A    A    A    A    A     A
2   10  name2  112       T       A    T    T    T    A     A
3   10  name3  223       G       T    T    G    T    T     G
4   10  name4  334       G       T    T    T    G    T     T
5   10  name5  445       C       C    C    C    C    C     C
6   10  name6  556       T       T    T    T    T    T     T
7   10  name7  667       C       C    C    C    C    C     C
8   10  name8  778       C       C    C    C    C    C     C
9   10  name9  889       G       T    T    T    T    T     G
10  10 name10 1000       C       T    C    T    T    C     T
```

I have tried using the function 'within' and 'apply' inside a for loop, but it seems like I am indexing wrongly. I bet this task is much easier in Perl, but I'd really like to use R for practicing.

Here's an example of the code I've tried:

```
within(df, {
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,6:length(df)]= ifelse(df[i,6:length(df)] == 0, df[i,4],df[i,5])
  }
})

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[,6:length(df)]= apply(df[,6:length(df)]==0,2,ifelse,df[i,4],df[i,5])
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Sincerely yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution 1

We can use `mutate_at` from the `dplyr` package. `df2` is the final output.

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)

# Process the data
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("col")), 
            .funs = function(Col){
              Col2 <- ifelse(Col == 1, allele2, allele1)
              return(Col2)
            })
```

#### Solution 2

We can use functions from both `tidyr` and `dplyr`. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(allele1 = as.character(allele1), allele2 = as.character(allele2)) %>%
  gather(Col, Value, contains("col")) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Value == 1, allele2, allele1)) %>%
  spread(Col, Value) %>%
  select(colnames(df))
```

#### Data Preparation

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Creating dataframe vectors
chr= rep(10,10)
id= paste0("name", 1:10)
pos= seq(1,1000, length.out = 10)
allele1= c("T","T","G","G","C","T","C","C","G","C")
allele2= c("A","A","T","T","C","T","C","C","T","T")
col6= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col7= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col8= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col9= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col10= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)

df= data.frame(chr,id, pos, allele1, allele2, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!! Actually, I had to replace ".vars" by ".cols" due to an error asking for this argument, but it worked perfectly.

If someone knows different ways to do that, I'd be equally grateful, since I am learning, practicing and using R quite recently.

Comment: `.col` is deprecated in the latest version of `dplyr`. If you update your `dplyr` to `0.7.1`, `.var` is the recommended argument to use.

Comment: Indeed, I've installed this package at the very beginning and didn't use or update it yet. Thanks again, @ycw !

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
chr= rep(10,10)
id= paste0("name", 1:10)
pos= seq(1,1000, length.out = 10)
allele1= c("T","T","G","G","C","T","C","C","G","C")
allele2= c("A","A","T","T","C","T","C","C","T","T")
set.seed(1) #for reproducibility
col6= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col7= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col8= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col9= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)
col10= sample(c(0,1),10, TRUE)

df= data.frame(chr,id, pos, allele1, allele2, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Note that as mentioned in the comments (thx @ycw) here I have stringsAsFactors = F so as to avoid the factor conversion!! Otherwise ifelse will just give integers instead of the character.

```
> df
   chr     id  pos allele1 allele2 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
1   10  name1    1       T       A    0    0    1    0     1
2   10  name2  112       T       A    0    0    0    1     1
3   10  name3  223       G       T    1    1    1    0     1
4   10  name4  334       G       T    1    0    0    0     1
5   10  name5  445       C       C    0    1    0    1     1
6   10  name6  556       T       T    1    0    0    1     1
7   10  name7  667       C       C    1    1    0    1     0
8   10  name8  778       C       C    1    1    0    0     0
9   10  name9  889       G       T    1    0    1    1     1
10  10 name10 1000       C       T    0    1    0    0     1

df[, c(6:10)] <- lapply(df[, c(6:10)], function(x) ifelse(x == 0, df[, 4], df[, 5]))

> df
   chr     id  pos allele1 allele2 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
1   10  name1    1       T       A    T    T    A    T     A
2   10  name2  112       T       A    T    T    T    A     A
3   10  name3  223       G       T    T    T    T    G     T
4   10  name4  334       G       T    T    G    G    G     T
5   10  name5  445       C       C    C    C    C    C     C
6   10  name6  556       T       T    T    T    T    T     T
7   10  name7  667       C       C    C    C    C    C     C
8   10  name8  778       C       C    C    C    C    C     C
9   10  name9  889       G       T    T    G    T    T     T
10  10 name10 1000       C       T    C    T    C    C     T
```

Comment: Good answer. But be careful that because `allele1` and `allele2` are factor, this solution fills in integers. Convert `allele1` and `allele2` to character before running this code.

Comment: A yes I did in my R session but forgot to add in the solution! Thank you!